# How do I determine the input field the user has selected from a web page downloaded from a server

Tags: javascript, ios

I have tried the following with no success, any help will be appreciated.

```
UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

[pb setString:passwordName];

NSString *jScriptString;

jScriptString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var output = {document.getElementById;" " ;output.innerHTML = document.activeElement.value = '%@'}",  passwordName];


[self.viewWebSite stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jScriptString];
```

Answer (score 0):

just guessing here, but when you uiwebview loads pages, you could add a .js file, local to your ios app, that adds a onfocus method to every input field found in the dom.  Then you can have that onfocus event pass up the element id to iOS via the window.location property, which webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: can monitor.